# Jenkins is creating separate workspace when running parallel nodes, but those temporary workspaces don't have all the files as original workspace

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing

Jenkins is creating separate workspace when running parallel nodes, but those temporary workspaces don't have all the files as original workspace. I want to use the file in the workspace. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before calling parallel deploy save the workspace in a variable something like this:

- **def workspace = sh(script:'pwd', returnStdout:true).trim()**

Now you can access all the file present in the original workspace.

**NOTE: This is just a workaround for this.**